# Multiple Name on one column using SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new at SQL and was assigned to create a table with fields with certain names. Names like:

- Student Number
- First Name
- Last Name
- Address
- City
- State
- Zip
- Date of Birth
- Major ID
- Advisor
- Enroll Date
- Total Credits Completed

My problem is that I can't find a way to name one column "Student Number" since I was directed to name them verbatim.

```
CREATE TABLE students(
    "Student Number" INT not null,
    "First Name" VARCHAR(255) not null,
    "Last Name" VARCHAR(255) not null,
    Address VARCHAR(255) not null,
    City VARCHAR(255) not null,
    State VARCHAR(255) not null,
    Zip INT not null,
    "Date of Birth" DATE not null,
    "Major ID" INT,
    Advisor VARCHAR(255),
    "Enroll Date" DATE,
    "Total Credits Complete" INT
);
```

This is the code that I'm trying to use and the error that I got was this:

> Error Static analysis:
>
> 5 errors were found during analysis.
>
> A symbol name was expected! (near ""Student Number"" at position 28)
>   At least one column definition was expected. (near ""Student Number""
>   at position 28) Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "255" at
>   position 76) Unexpected beginning of statement. (near ""Last Name"" at
>   position 87) Unrecognized statement type. (near "VARCHAR" at position
>   99) SQL query:
>
> CREATE TABLE students( "Student Number" INT, "First Name"
>   VARCHAR(255), "Last Name" VARCHAR(255), Address VARCHAR(255), City
>   VARCHAR(255), State VARCHAR(255), Zip INT, "Date of Birth" DATE,
>   "Major ID" INT, Advisor VARCHAR(255), "Enroll Date" DATE, "Total
>   Credits Complete" INT )
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> *1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"Student Number" INT,
>       "First Name" VARCHAR(255),
>       "Last Name" VARCHAR(2' at line 2

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for taking your time to go through my question.

Comment: removed wrong `SQL Server` tag

Comment: Try this query by removing double quotation from column names. Use [ ] instead of double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backticks instead of double quotations.

Code will be

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    `Student Number` INT,
    `First Name` VARCHAR(255),
    `Last Name` VARCHAR(255),
    Address VARCHAR(255),
    City VARCHAR(255),
    State VARCHAR(255),
    Zip INT,
    `Date of Birth` DATE,
    `Major ID` INT,
    Advisor VARCHAR(255),
    `Enroll Date` DATE,
    `Total Credits Complete` INT
);
```

You have to use the backticks when selecting from this table.

```
SELECT `Student Number` FROM Students
```

So, preferable way is , not having space in column name.

Comment: Started writing when there was no answer. Thats why I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using whitespace in your table/column/DB names.  If you *must* use whitespace, then the way to escape such a name in MySQL is to use backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    `Student Number` INT,
    `First Name` VARCHAR(255),
    `Last Name` VARCHAR(255),
    Address VARCHAR(255),
    City VARCHAR(255),
    State VARCHAR(255),
    Zip INT,
    `Date of Birth` DATE,
    `Major ID` INT,
    Advisor VARCHAR(255),
    `Enroll Date` DATE,
    `Total Credits Complete` INT
);
```

But again, I think it would be far preferable to *not* have spaces in your column names, so instead of `Student Number` use something like `Student_Number`.

Note: Double quotes should work if you have ANSI mode enabled on your MySQL server.  But I think ANSI mode is not enabled by default.

Comment: Dude thanks for the info. And unfortunately, my instructor wants us to use the names with the whitespace or else I would have used underscores.

Comment: @CholoBoy Then use backticks, but realize that you will therefore have to backticks _everywhere_ in your code.

Comment: Other things to annoy recalcitrant instructors, `INT`s probably should be `UNSIGNED`, `VARCHAR(255)` is an arbitrary length and not related to the length of the fields, all fields probably could be `NOT NULL`